# where is I am making mistake when I trying write the data in SaveMovie function and read the data and count number of movies in LoadMovie function

Tags: c

The movie.dat file had duplicate data. When i use degger it was the information pass to main_s in save function is right and number of movie is also write so why it save some part twice.

```c
void SaveMovie(Movie main_s[], int number_s)
{
    int i;

    ptr = fopen("D:\\MOVIE.DAT", "wb");

    for(i = 0; i < number_s; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&main_s[i], sizeof(Movie), number_s, ptr);
    }
    fclose(ptr);
}

int LoadMovie(Movie main_l[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int number = 0;

    if ((ptr = fopen("D:\\MOVIE.DAT", "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        j = 100;
    }

    if (j == 0)
    {
        ptr = fopen("D:\\MOVIE.DAT", "rb");
        while (fread(&main_l[i], sizeof(Movie), 1, ptr))
        {
            i++;
            number++;
        }

        fclose(ptr);
        return number - 1;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file twice in `LoadMovie()`?

Comment: The problem does not appear to be in the code you have shown. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can reproduce the problem. For example, how did you come to this conclusion: " it save some part twice"? Where is the verification code that provides that data?